# Alert dialog not properly displaying message

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, message, alert

I have a problem with long messages in alert dialog. For some reason if text do not fit in a single line words are splited in the half instead of moved to the next line. 
For example text like

```
aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh
```

is displaying like

```
aaaa bbbb cccc dd
dd eeee ffff gggg
hhhh
```

instead of

```
aaaa bbbb cccc
dddd eeee ffff
gggg hhhh
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Which dialog do you use? How do you use it? A screenshot is better than text.

Comment: I use alert dialog inside dialog fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can just start new lines where necessary:

```
.setMessage("These words will be on line 1" + "\n" + "These will be on line 2")
```

The `\n` starts a new line.